# What is wrong with this PDO transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have total of 4 queries in my code. I am using a PDO transaction
on the first 3 queries. It execute the code correctly but on the fourth query it gives me an error:

> Error occurred:There is no active transaction.

What is the solution for it?

Why do the 3 queries commit changes to the database, even if it gives the 4th query an error.

This is the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';
    try {

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
    $temp = "123456";
    $temp1 = "LHPL002";
    $temp2 = "Declined";
    $temp3 = "This is the reason";
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tble_transaction SET  signed=? WHERE tracknum= ?");
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $temp2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                $stmt->bindParam(2, $temp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

        echo "good";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("select  tracknum,   login_id from tble_document where tracknum= ?");
                $stmt->bindParam(1, $temp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                $stmt->execute();
                if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                     $logid =  $row['login_id'];
                     echo $logid;
                     echo "good 1";
                     $conn->commit();

                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tble_declined ( tracknum, signatoryid,  reason,  status, login_id) VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            $stmt->bindParam(1, $temp, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                            $stmt->bindParam(2, $temp1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                            $stmt->bindParam(3, $temp3, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                            $stmt->bindParam(4, $temp2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                            $stmt->bindParam(5, $logid, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                                 echo "good 2";
                                 $conn->commit();

                                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select signatorycontact from tble_signatory where login_id= ?");
                                        $stmt->bindParam(1, $logid, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                                        $stmt->execute();
                                        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                                            echo "good 3";
                                            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                            echo  $row['signatorycontact'];

                                             $conn->commit();
                                        }else {

                                        $conn->rollBack();
                                        }
                            }else {

                            $conn->rollBack();
                            }
                }else {

                $conn->rollBack();
                }
    }else  {

            $conn->rollBack();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
    }   

?>
```

Comment: You have `$conn->commit();` in there...

Comment: You *commit* the transaction and then you're not starting a new one... So there's *no active transaction* when you try to *commit* the next time...

Answer (score 1):

You start transaction one time

```
$temp3 = "This is the reason";
$conn->beginTransaction();
```

then, after two queries you commit transaction

```
echo "good 1";
$conn->commit();
```

and after that you execute also one query and try to commit them

```
echo "good 2";
$conn->commit();
```

but you haven't active transaction, because you commit a transaction above (in the first commit).

[Here](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.begintransaction.php#116669) you can find comment about nested transactions. I think that is what you need.